# vb Format(now + 1, "mm") equals plus one day or one month?

Tags: date, vb6, format

Since "mm" displays the month, I wasn't sure

```
Format(now + 1, "mm")
```

will now + 1 month or + 1 day
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now + 1 adds one day. Doesn't matter how you're formatting it.

Dates are stored internally as the whole part of a real number, and are calculated as the number of days since Dec 30, 1899.
So today, Sept 20, 2012, is stored internally as 41172. Tomorrow will be 41173.

And in case you're wondering, time is stored as the decimal part of the number, and is calculated as the percent of the day. So 41172.5 would be noon today.

Comment: Very interesting... When you mention "internally," do you mean like computer internally? server and etc?

Comment: Yes, computer internally. Or at least it's how it's presented to us in VB. I think VB is actually written in C, so how C stores it I don't know. But as far as it matters when working in VB, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't guess about it. Use the function built specifically for this, **DateAdd**. See [VB6 help topic on DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262710%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) for the complete details.

```
Date  = DateAdd("m", 1, Now)
```

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I was reading someone's code :p

Comment: I agree that it's much better to use this function. Much more readable, and less prone to errors.

Comment: +1. Took the liberty of editing your post to link to the **VB6** docs not the .Net docs :)